# Python: Call asynchronous code from synchronous method when there is already an event loop running

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, fastapi

I am working with FastAPI and uvloop to serve a REST API in an efficient way.

I have a lot of asynchronous code that make calls to remote resources such as a database, a storage, etc, those functions looks like this:

```py
async def _get_remote_resource(key: str) -> Resource:
    # do some async work
    return resource
```

I'm implementing an interface to an existing Abstract Base Class where I need to use the asynchronous function from above in a synchronous method. I have done something like:

```py
class Resource:
     def __str__(self):
         resource = asyncio.run_until_complete(_get_remote_resource(self.key))
         return f"{resource.pk}"
```

Great! Now I do an endpoint in fastapi to make this work accesible:

```py
@app.get("")
async def get(key):
     return str(Resource(key))
```

The problem is that FastAPI already gets and event loop running, using uvloop, and then the asynchronous code fails because the loop is already running.

Is there any way I can call the asynchronous method from the synchronous method in the class? Or do I have to rethink the structure of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime error is designed precisely to prevent what you are trying to do. `run_until_complete` is a blocking call, and using it inside an async def will halt the outer event loop.

The straightforward fix is to expose the needed functionality through an actual async method, e.g.:

```
class Resource:
    def name(self):
        return loop.run_until_complete(self.name_async())

    async def name_async(self):
        resource = await _get_remote_resource(self.key)
        return f"{resource.pk}"
```

Then in fastapi you'd access the API in the native way:

```
@app.get("")
async def get(key):
     return await Resource(key).name_async()
```

You could also define `__str__(self)` to return `self.name()`, but that's best avoided because something as basic as `str()` should be callable from within asyncio as well (due to use in logging, debugging, etc.).

Comment: Yes, I agree the straightforward fix is using an async method, however, the class Resource is actually an implementation of a Abstract Base Class so the methods are already defined.

Comment: @NicolasMartinez That's new information. I don't think such a design is going to work - you'll need to switch to an async-aware ABC.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include that in the question! Editing ASAP. Thanks for your help.

Comment: We did switch to an async-aware aBC (which provides sync and async methods for almost everything) did fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to complement the @user4815162342 answer.

`FastAPI` is an asychronous framework. I would suggest sticking to a few principles:

- Do not execute IO operations in synchronous functions in a blocking way. Prepare this resource asynchronously and already pass the ready data to the synchronous function (this principle can be called an asynchronous dependency for synchronous code).
- If you still need to perform a blocking IO operation in a synchronous code, then do it in a separate thread. And wait for this result asynchronously by means of `asyncio` (`def` endpoint, `run_in_executor` with `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `def` background task).
- If you need to do a blocking CPU-bound operation, then delegate its execution to a separate process (the simplest way `run_in_executor` with `ProcessPoolExecutor` or any task queue).

Comment: Should "a synchronous code" in the second bullet be "asynchronous code"?

Comment: By synchronous code, I mean here a piece of code that does not contain asynchronous calls, but includes preparatory actions and a call to a synchronous blocking function.